# an error happened when change the color of tables in php printf function

Tags: php, html, printf, html-table

I want to change the color of text of the table in php file using printf function.
But when I used this two method , I failed.
Can you tell me how could that happen?
And how can I manage to change the color?
 method A:

```
 <?php   
      printf('<tr>');  
      printf('<td><font color='red'>abc</font></td>');  
      printf('</tr>');
  ?>
```

method B:

```
 <?php
  printf('<tr>');
  printf('<td style="color:red">abc</td>');
  printf('</tr>');
 ?>
```

PS: the original question:(this is a part of code)

```
 $userrow = mysql_fetch_array($userqueryresult);
            $thisuserid = $userrow[0];
            $user_type=$userrow[1];

printf("   <td valign = 'center'  width='40%%'>
<a href='show_user.php?u=%d'>
<font color='red'>%s</font></a></td>\n",$thisuserid, $key);
```

In fact ,When I use color="red" ,it fails while color=‘red', It worked.
Is there any difference between " " "and " ' "?
But as  Julie Pelletier said ," abc "it worked.
This is also " " ".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both cases are missing the `<table>` tag which tells the browser to process the content as a table.

The first error stands out with the quotes leaving `red` unquoted.  You can easily fix it by using different quotes:

```
<?php   
    printf('<table><tr>');  
    printf('<td><font color="red">abc</font></td>');  
    printf('</tr></table>');
```

For the second one, it works as is as long as you put it in a `<table>`:

```
<?php
    printf('<table><tr>');
    printf('<td style="color:red">abc</td>');
    printf('</tr></table>');
```

If you must include quotes in a string, you either have to use a different type of quotes (`'`, `"`) or prefix them with a backslash (`\`).

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry to interrupt you with such a low question.But the original question is not like this . I edited it. Can you see it again?

Comment: Your main problem is the fact that you don't realize that the interpreter can not guess what you're doing if you put all types of quotes inside other quotes.  You, as the programmer, has to make sure the quotes are easily understood by it.

Comment: I think I have realized where i was wrong for your help.Thank you!